# Joomla 2.5 gallery with subfolders

Tags: php, joomla, gallery

Folders structure:

```
|_image
|__image2
|__image3
```

For example, sigplus(joomla module) usage:

```
{gallery}image2{/gallery}
```

show all images in image2 folder.

But `{gallery}image{/gallery}`
dont'n display anysing(